# postgresql - create and index containing concatenated fields

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create an index that has a field containing concatenated results from several other fields in postgresql.

For example I have an address:

```
BLACKPOOL FYLDE & WYRE SOCIETY FOR THE BLIND, PRINCESS ALEXANDRA HOME FOR THE BLIND, BOSWORTH PLACE, BLACKPOOL, FY4 1SH
```

The above is made up of 5 fields, sperated by commas in the example. I would like to create a single index field that contains the data from the 5 fields.

I would like my index to contain 3 fields: uprn, AddressText, wkb_geometry
AddressText would contain the above example with the 5 fields concatenated into it , the other 2 fields are just regular fields.

I know how to concatenate in a query "||" and that works fine but can't find anywhere that explains how to do the above. The way I have described is how the address data provider (Ordnance Survey) explains it should be done, but they give no example code to create the index.

I could create a new table with the above, but would have to re-create it when the address data is updated.

The actual query I would use to build an address is this, as you can see its more complicated than just 5 fields:

```
SELECT uprn,
(
CASE WHEN organisation_name IS NOT NULL THEN organisation_name || ', ' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN sao_text IS NOT NULL THEN sao_text || ', ' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN sao_start_number IS NOT NULL THEN sao_start_number::text ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN sao_start_suffix IS NOT NULL THEN  sao_start_suffix ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN sao_end_number IS NOT NULL THEN '-' || sao_end_number ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN sao_end_suffix IS NOT NULL THEN sao_end_suffix ELSE '' END

|| CASE WHEN sao_start_number IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' ELSE '' END

|| CASE WHEN pao_text IS NOT NULL THEN pao_text || ', ' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN pao_start_number IS NOT NULL THEN pao_start_number::text ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN pao_start_suffix IS NOT NULL THEN  pao_start_suffix ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN pao_end_number IS NOT NULL THEN '-' || pao_end_number ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN pao_end_suffix IS NOT NULL THEN pao_end_suffix ELSE '' END

|| CASE WHEN pao_start_number IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' ELSE '' END

|| CASE WHEN street_description IS NOT NULL THEN street_description || ', ' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN locality IS NOT NULL THEN locality || ', ' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN town_name IS NOT NULL THEN town_name ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN administrative_area <> town_name THEN ', ' || administrative_area ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN postcode_locator IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' || postcode_locator ELSE '' END
) AS AddressText, wkb_geometry
FROM addressbase.address
LIMIT 1000
```

Unfortunately I can't just do this:

```
CREATE INDEX AddressSearchIndex ON addressbase.address (uprn,
(
CASE WHEN organisation_name IS NOT NULL THEN organisation_name || ', ' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN sao_text IS NOT NULL THEN sao_text || ', ' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN sao_start_number IS NOT NULL THEN sao_start_number::text ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN sao_start_suffix IS NOT NULL THEN  sao_start_suffix ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN sao_end_number IS NOT NULL THEN '-' || sao_end_number ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN sao_end_suffix IS NOT NULL THEN sao_end_suffix ELSE '' END

|| CASE WHEN sao_start_number IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' ELSE '' END

|| CASE WHEN pao_text IS NOT NULL THEN pao_text || ', ' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN pao_start_number IS NOT NULL THEN pao_start_number::text ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN pao_start_suffix IS NOT NULL THEN  pao_start_suffix ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN pao_end_number IS NOT NULL THEN '-' || pao_end_number ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN pao_end_suffix IS NOT NULL THEN pao_end_suffix ELSE '' END

|| CASE WHEN pao_start_number IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' ELSE '' END

|| CASE WHEN street_description IS NOT NULL THEN street_description || ', ' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN locality IS NOT NULL THEN locality || ', ' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN town_name IS NOT NULL THEN town_name ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN administrative_area <> town_name THEN ', ' || administrative_area ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN postcode_locator IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' || postcode_locator ELSE '' END
) AS AddressText, wkb_geometry);
```

The example would then allow me to do a search like this:

```
SELECT UPRN, AddressText, wkb_geometry FROM AddressSearchIndex
WHERE
AddressText LIKE ‘%4%’ AND
AddressText LIKE ‘%HIGH%’ AND
AddressText LIKE ‘%STREET%’ AND
AddressText LIKE ‘%WESTVILLE%’ AND
AddressText LIKE ‘%WV17%’;
```

Comment: BTW `CASE WHEN sao_text IS NOT NULL THEN sao_text || ', ' ELSE '' END` gives the same result as `coalesce(sao_text||', ','')`

Comment: I don't think the example search is all that great anyway. My internet searches appear to throw up lots of examples of Full Text Searches using TSVECTOR but I'm thrown off this due to official examples from the data provider saying differently. The examples are generic SQL not specific for postgresql though. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are searching for the `materialized view` feature, which is added in PostgreSQL 9.3 https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html

Comment: @pozs there is no need in MVIEW for this case. A simple functional index or a column+trigger will do the job.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko thanks, coalesce is a bit easier to read.

Comment: @StevenH A simple (`BTREE`) index font help for queries that have `LIKE '%something%'`. You need GIN or GIST for that. Use the information you have found for postgres full text search.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko *simple functional index* - technically, yes. But repeating this expression every time you need to query it? - and *column+trigger* is just a dumb mview.

Comment: @pozs "column+trigger is almost a mview" not even close :) . Current postgres cant auto refresh MVIEW. And with separate MVIEW you will have to join back to base table.

Comment: @pozs As for "repeating this expression every time you need to query it" - just create a simple VIEW on top of the expression and query the view.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko That's true, but they both need a trigger & both use a sperate *space* (column vs. another table) to store aggregated data. In my opinion the latter (another table) is more clear. -- Simple view with an expression based index *is* an option, but mviews is created for this use case.

Comment: @pozs MVIEW looks very interesting, reading through the documentation.

Comment: Nice to see someone else having fun with Address Base and address matching. What is the problem with tsvector?. Have OS really advised against it?

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko thanks looks like I would need either GIN or GIST as you suggest. Still confused between column+trigger and pozs suggestion of MVIEW which does look interesting and maybe faster. I have another database which uses the column+trigger approach.

Comment: @JohnBarça They haven't specifically advised against it, the approach above is the only example I have seen and is in the Addressbase getting started guide. Never used tsvector or mview previously, so a learning curve.

Comment: And why would you want to to include the geometry in the index? Are you interested in fuzzy search (address matching) or just exact matches, but on unknown combinations of input fields. I haven't done anything with AB, but I have spent a long time at the coal face with AL2.

Comment: @JohnBarça you are right I don't need the geometry, the OS examples just had me baffled. Their example index looks more like an mview to my mind than an actual index. Never really used AL2, used to use address-point but was asked to move away from it and AL2.

Answer (score 1):

Use the information you can find in the internet on `Postgres full text search` or Postgres official manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html

As I see you will need:

1) An GIN or GIST index on your expression (see full text search examples).

2) Create a simple VIEW (not MVIEW) on the base table + your expression.

3) Use full text search queries to your VIEW.